# Cannot establish connections between clients on JRE1.8 and servers on JRE1.7

Tags: ssl, java-8

we have a client application compiled with JDK1.8, and an external server application runs with JRE1.7 or earlier versions.  We don't know the exact JRE version of the server side. The problem here is that we cannot establish secure connections between them. We know that Java 1.8 enables TLS1.2 by default, and according to corresponding RFCs and Oracle blogs, TLS1.2 is compatible with TLS1.1 and TLS1.0. So, even if the server side uses TLS1.1 or 1.0, it should work as expected. We don't know why. The error message says something like "caused by missing of certificates or cipher suite not supported". We also used SSLab to analyze the server side, and got something like "cipher suite not supported or mismatch". Very confusing because if we compile the client side with java1.7, it works fine. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Could this be off-topic? You might want to take a look at the other stack exchange sites - there's likely a site more appropriate for this.

Comment: Unfortunately the information you provide are probably not sufficient to debug the problem. There are no general problems of the SSL stacks  of Java 8 so this needs to be specific to your setup. Thus you need to provide specific information about this setup. You should also provide the exact error messages you got and the report from SSLLabs. A minimal example showing your problem would be helpful too. If it is a public site you might even publish the URL so one can try oneself.